# How to write a bridge

Tags: solidity, tokens, decentralized-exchange, bridge

I'm thinking about writing an bridge between 2 blockchain, one of them is EVM and the another one is not.
How i can do that??  i think i need a lot of liquidity in 2 side of bridge and when user deposit tokens in contract and emit the event of deposit, then my smart contract in target blockchain get event & send token to user wallet address. but actually in essence it's not bridge, anyone has better idea for this?

Answer (score 0):

You can read here and try it: https://docs.tokenbridge.net/ - opensource all components and you can set up by yourself